# Wrong URL redirect after login CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect

I’m working on a project using CakePHP and I’m having a little problem. When an unauthenticated user tries to access to a restricted page, they are redirected to the login page, which is a normal behavior on the security management of CakePHP using the Auth Component.

However, once the user logs in the application, it redirects the user to the wrong url. I.E. Instead of redirecting the user to the url it tried to access before, the application redirects the user to something like: localhost/myApplication/folder/myApplication/folder/urlUserTriedToAccess.

For some reason, the path of the project has been written twice and I don´t know why. I hope someone could give me a hint of what could be happening. Thanks a lot!

**This is the code in the AppController where I set the values for the Auth component:**

```
public $components = array(
  'DebugKit.Toolbar',
  'Session',
  'Auth' => array(
    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'home'),
    'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'home'),
    'authError' => "Debes iniciar sesión para entrar en esta página",
    'authorize' => array('Controller') // Added this line
));
```

**This is the code in the Login action within the UsersController:**

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid user', 'default', array('class'=>'alert alert-error'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.  I'm assuming you're using the Auth component.  The Auth component has a property, loginRedirect where you can define where it will redirect to after login, so I would check that.  Also check in your login action.

Comment: @Kai I just edited the post and pasted the code, I don't see any problem in it. May be you could give me some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: It seems everything is ok.. try to clear cache

Comment: That is a known issue in earlier cake2.x versions (due to some base url issue). Upgrade to the latest 2.4 master and this will most likely be resolved. Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like the code below after logging in to verify the redirect is working properly:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'anyRestrictedController','action'=>'index'));
```

Also, try using redirectUrl() instead of redirect().

Comment: I did what you said and used a specific Url inside the redirect method and it worked. Thanks.